# How to correctly inherit and hide base method

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I have the following inheritance:

```
class A
{
    void Configure(object param1) {...};
}

class B : A
{
    void Configure(object param1) {...}; // The method is not defined in B, it is available from the base class. This is just the desired interface of class B
}

class C : A
{
    void Configure(object param1, object param2) {...};
}
```

I don't want class C to have a Configure with param1 visible as in this case it will leave the object incomplete.

I tried overriding but override cannot change the visibility.

The only approach I found is calling the class A method `protected void ConfigureBase(object param1) {...};` and making method Configure of class B call ConfigureBase.

As I'm not completely happy with this design as it makes me redefine on each class the Configure is there a standard way of handling this?

Comment: This looks a LOT like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You are having issues with your solution to some problem you aren't telling us.  What is the goal of each base and derived type?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I think that the answers below are enough to understand what I need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.  You could possibly have the method just throw an exception so it couldn't be used, but one of the fundamental principles of inheritance in programming is that a child can always be treated as if it were of it's parent's type.  What should the following do:

```
A obj = new C();

obj.Configure(new object());//should this work, or not?
```

By design, there is no way to restrict a child to not be able to do something it's parent could do.  You would need to more fundamentally re-design your program if `C` really shouldn't have access to a `Configure(object obj)` method.  This could possibly mean that `C` really shouldn't extend `A` (It might make sense for both `A` and `C` to implement a common interface.), or just that `Configure` really shouldn't be a public method of that type.  Without knowing more, it's hard to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Well, class A has lots of code implementing the common behavior of B and C, it's just that C has one parameter more than B so I really think that C is a superclass of A. Your example wouldn't work because class A is an abstract protected class containing what's common from B and C.

Comment: @SoMoS My point is that it's a fundamental concept of polymorphism that you can treat an object as if it is one of it's base classes, so the code that I've posted *must* be able to work; what you want to do would violate that.  If `A` is an abstract base class then perhaps it just shouldn't have a `Configure` method. It sounds like just `B` and `C` should have it, with the appropriate overload.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a standard way of handling this?

Yes: make configuration process part of the initialization.

Instead of exposing `Configure`, perform all initialization in the constructor. This will let your classes expose only the alternatives that make sense:

```
class A {
    public A(object param1) {...};
}

class B : A {
    public B(object param1) : base(param1) {...}; // This re-exposes A's constructor
}

class C : A {
    // Note that A(param1) constructor is not available, even though C inherits A
    public C(object param1, object param2) : base(param1)  {...};
}
```

Comment: I cannot mostly because MVVM and IoC. I loved the old times where you could put all what was needed on the constructor.

Comment: @SoMoS Well, then "protect and publish" method that you described is the best approach: it lets you stay in control of exposing a `Configure` with the right signature with very little work.